# node.js cygwin windows xp error ./configure

Tags: node.js, compilation, installation, configure

I already did `ash.exe /bin/rebaseall -v` without errors but I still get the following error when trying to `./configure`:

```
Checking for program g++ or c++ : /usr/bin/g++
/node/wscript:232: error: could not configure a cxx compiler
```

I installed gcc4-g++ 4.5.x, openssl and all the needed dependencies.

Comment: Are you carefully following the steps from: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-(Windows) ? It suggests running another command and then rebooting after rebase.

Comment: I had no errors with baseall and I rebooted the system and still get the same error. I don't know what's wrong...

Comment: Yay! Sucess! I deleted cygwin and resintalled it and did the rebaseall again and everything is working now.

Answer (score 2):

Are you carefully following the steps from: [github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-(Windows)](http://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-%28Windows%29) ?

It suggests running another command and then rebooting after rebase.